# Can't mount USB drive On Fedora 37

Tags: fedora, mount, usb

I was working on creating Linux From Scratch and suddenly I can no longer mount my USB drive. When I `sudo mount /dev/sdf2 /mnt` I get an error `kernel: JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering data`. Here's full log from `journalctl -f`
Then the `mount` command freezes and I have to `kill` it.
Did I manage to break my partitions? Is there a way to fix it?

```
Dec 03 12:20:05 fedora sudo[4196]:   jedrek : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/jedrek ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -f
Dec 03 12:20:05 fedora sudo[4196]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Dec 03 12:20:05 fedora audit[4196]: USER_START pid=4196 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
Dec 03 12:20:06 fedora kernel: JBD2: recovery failed
Dec 03 12:20:06 fedora kernel: EXT4-fs (sdf2): error loading journal
Dec 03 12:20:18 fedora audit: BPF prog-id=85 op=LOAD
Dec 03 12:20:18 fedora systemd[1]: Starting fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Dec 03 12:20:18 fedora systemd[1]: Started fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Dec 03 12:20:18 fedora audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=fprintd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 03 12:20:22 fedora audit[4201]: USER_AUTH pid=4201 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_usertype,pam_localuser,pam_unix acct="jedrek" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Dec 03 12:20:22 fedora audit[4201]: USER_ACCT pid=4201 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="jedrek" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Dec 03 12:20:22 fedora audit[4201]: USER_CMD pid=4201 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='cwd="/home/jedrek" cmd=6D6F756E74202F6465762F73646632202F6D6E74 exe="/usr/bin/sudo" terminal=pts/0 res=success'
Dec 03 12:20:22 fedora sudo[4201]:   jedrek : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jedrek ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mount /dev/sdf2 /mnt
Dec 03 12:20:22 fedora audit[4201]: CRED_REFR pid=4201 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_localuser,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Dec 03 12:20:22 fedora sudo[4201]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Dec 03 12:20:22 fedora audit[4201]: USER_START pid=4201 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Dec 03 12:20:41 fedora systemd[1]: flatpak-system-helper.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 03 12:20:41 fedora audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=flatpak-system-helper comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Dec 03 12:20:43 fedora kernel: JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering data block 8479136 in log
Dec 03 12:20:43 fedora kernel: JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering data block 8389614 in log
```